# How do I address an item in a sequence when using tokenize()

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have an HTML that contains a style attribute with a list of values separated by semicolons:

```
<td style="border-width:1pt;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid">
```

I want to split this list:

```
<xsl:variable name="astyle"><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@style, ';')"/></xsl:variable>
```

This gives me a sequence. Now I want to select the first item in the sequence.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$astyle[1]"/>
```

result:
"border-width:1pt border-color:#FFFFFF border-style:solid"

so that's the entire sequence instead of the first item in the sequence.

I can't find any documentation on this.

Edit: it seems my assumption is incorrect. Tokenize() contains a sequence of 1 item. I was expecting 3 items.

How can I split a string into items that can be addressed individually?
I want to do something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="$astyle[1]"/>
```

and get:

```
border-width:1pt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:variable select="tokenize(...)" name="astyle"/>`, then the value of the variable is a sequence and `$astyle[1]` works.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding the difference between those two. Thanks!

Comment: The XPath expression `tokenize(...)` indeed returns a sequence of strings, but `<xsl:value-of select="some-xpath-expression"/>` creates a text node with the string value of the XPath expression. And when you put that into an `xsl:variable` your variable as its value has a document fragment node containing a text node. Meanwhile, `<xsl:variable name="variable-name" select="some-xpath-expression"/>` just binds the value of the XPath expression to the variable.

Comment: So in all cases, where you simply want to evaluate an XPath expression and store the evaluation result in a variable, use the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable` to provide the XPath expression.